# Tipping in shared ride vans

Tags: usa, airport-transfer, tipping

When taking shared ride vans in the United States are you expected to tip? If so, how much?

To be clear I'm talking about services where you are lumped along with 5-6 strangers in a van that then takes each passenger to their destination from the airport (or vica versa).

It's not quite a taxi (where I would tip) and it's not quite a bus (where I wouldn't tip), but occupies some sort of middle ground between the two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did such rides in the US to airports, it was usually with people I know or at least I knew some of the people in the van. I personally tip as I understood that the drivers are usually on minimum wage. We collect the tips in an envelope and pass it to the driver upon arrival.

If you do not know the people with you, take the lead and take your tip out and ask the rest if they want to add to it, people will do. I assume it is easier when you are going to the airport as most if not all people will leave at the same time, but nonetheless if you are being picked up from the airport then do this as soon as everyone is onboard, let the last person pass it to the driver.

Comment: Looking to stay in the competition, huh? :P +1 for taking matters in your own hands if other people on the ride are hesitating.

Comment: Jo,competition is still active for tomorrow as well. I am simply answering a question out of experience 

Answer (score 2):

I live in the NYC area.  NYC cab drivers, and the like, surprisingly earn less money than drivers in some smaller cities, such as Boston, but all drivers need tips.  If a driver lifts a bag, I give at least $1 per bag, no matter how short the trip (e.g., a free shuttle at an airport).  In general, 15 to 20% of the fare I pay is my rule of thumb.